# Subsetting stacked pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a small sample that looks like this:

```
    Country Item                                             mean_area
84  Albania Sunflower seed                                    1900
85  Albania Tangerines, mandarins, clementines, satsumas      0
86  Albania Tobacco, unmanufactured                           5700
87  Albania Tomatoes                                          5400
88  Albania Vegetables, freshnes                                0
89  Albania Vegetables, leguminousnes                           20
90  Albania Vetches                                           6200
91  Albania Watermelons                                       8300
92  Algeria Wheat                                             112000
93  Algeria Almonds, with shell                               27150
```

The full dataframe is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b413htrn39m2wzg/zzzzz.csv?dl=0

I want to select the top 10 countries based on sum of mean_area(the full dataframe has nearly 200 countries), and select the top 5 crops for each country (again based on mean_area)

I can get the top 10 countries based on mean_area as follows:

```
  df = (df_stacked
         .loc[df_stacked['Country']
         .isin(df_stacked.groupby('Country')
         .sum()
         .nlargest(10, 'mean_area').index)])
```

How do I then convert it to a dataframe with only top 5 crops for each of these countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a list of the top 10 countries by mean area total.

```
top10 = df.groupby('Country_FAO', sort=False).mean_area.sum().nlargest(10).index
```

Subset your dataframe based on the top 10.

```
df = df[df.Country_FAO.isin(top10)]
```

Get the top 10 country totals (for sorting in final step).

```
df['country_total'] = df.groupby(['Country_FAO']).mean_area.transform(sum)
```

Sort the top 10 by country and then by mean_area in descending order, group by country and take the top five using `head(5)`, and then sort the results in descending order (i.e. largest first) using the country totals and mean_area per item.

```
>>> (df
     .sort_values(['Country_FAO', 'mean_area'], ascending=False)
     .groupby('Country_FAO')
     .head(5)
     .sort_values(['country_total', 'mean_area'], ascending=False))

     Country_FAO             Item  mean_area  country_total
3201       India      Rice, paddy   44712000      177423048
3218       India            Wheat   27486000      177423048
3182       India           Millet   13012200      177423048
3206       India          Sorghum    9856400      177423048
3204       India      Seed cotton    8576500      177423048
1440       China      Rice, paddy   29961890      160425183
1470       China            Wheat   26653290      160425183
1410       China            Maize   23056270      160425183
1449       China         Soybeans    9306760      160425183
1439       China         Rapeseed    7494360      160425183
7458         USA            Maize   29315744      101345306
7489         USA         Soybeans   29302790      101345306
7505         USA            Wheat   21474065      101345306
7486         USA      Seed cotton    5282000      101345306
7488         USA          Sorghum    3126630      101345306
...
```